DateInput React Admin while using it in filter : Warning: value prop on input should not be null
I'm currently struggling on a bug with react admin, I have a list component on which I want to use a filter with different types of values (boolean, number, string and date). To get set up a date on the filter I use DateInput Component from React-Admin, but I encountered the following problem:

Warning: value prop on input should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or undefined for uncontrolled components.
input

I tried setting defaultValue on DateInput, which didn't worked since I have the alwaysOn parameter. I tried using filterDefaultValues on the List component but it didn't worked neither. Here is the filter code:
const ProjectFilters = (props) => {

    return (
        <Filter variant="standard" {...props}>
            
            <DateInput label="Dossier déposé après le" source="beginning_date_submit.gte" alwaysOn />
            <DateInput label="Dossier déposé avant le" source="beginning_date_submit.lte" alwaysOn />
            
        </Filter>
    );
};

And here is the List parameters:
<List
  title={<ProjectOffersTitle />}
  exporter={false}
  actions={<ProjectOffersListActions record={getRecord} />}
  filterDefaultValues={{ "beginning_date_submit.gte": "2029-01-01" }}
  filters={<ProjectOffersFilters />}
  filter={{ id: getRecord ? getRecord.ids_reconciliation : [] }}
  sort={{
    field: `row_updated`,
    order: 'DESC',
  }}
  perpage={25}
  pagination={<Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 75, 100]} />}
  resource={"reconciliation"}
  location={locate}
  hasCreate={false}
  hasEdit={true}
  hasShow={true}
  hasList={true}
/>


Hello. Following the React-admin doc regarding the filters prop, my understanding is that you need to pass an array of <Input> and not a React component. I wonder where did you find this example?
